# What is the cleanest way to leverage Forms Authentication from ServiceStack?

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, servicestack

I'm trying to integrate ServiceStack with an existing Web Forms site. The site uses Forms Authentication along with some custom authentication logic involving database calls, etc.

How can I secure ServiceStack calls using the same mechanism? Reading the [docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization), it seems I should write a custom auth provider that inherits from `CredentialsAuthProvider` to do the database check, etc. and add a request filter to apply the `AuthenticateAttribute` to each request.  Do I also need to set the forms auth ticket, once authenticated, and check the ticket on each request? Where would I do those things?

Am I missing anything? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [CustomAuthenticationMvc](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/tree/master/CustomAuthenticationMvc) UseCase project for an example of integrating MVC Forms Authentication with ServiceStack's Auth Providers.

Specifically the [AccountController.Login()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/CustomAuthenticationMvc/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L41) method shows how to call ServiceStack from MVC:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var authService = AppHostBase.Instance.TryResolve<AuthService>();
        authService.RequestContext = CreateRequestContext();
        var response = authService.Authenticate(new Auth
        {
            UserName = model.UserName,
            Password = model.Password,
            RememberMe = model.RememberMe
        });

        // add ASP.NET auth cookie
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", 
        "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: My authentication logic can return multiple values: "user not found," "locked out," etc. Is it possible to support that using a `CredentialAuthProvider`?

Comment: It's possible, but no one's contributed support to do that yet :)